# Can someone explain this for/in loop to me?

Tags: javascript, for-in-loop

```
/*
  Write each function according to the instructions.
  

  When a function's parameters reference `cart`, it references an object that looks like the one that follows.
  {
    "Gold Round Sunglasses": { quantity: 1, priceInCents: 1000 },
    "Pink Bucket Hat": { quantity: 2, priceInCents: 1260 }
  }
*/

function calculateCartTotal(cart) {
  let total = 0;
  for (const item in cart){
    let quantity = Object.values(cart[item])[0];
    let price = Object.values(cart[item])[1];
        total += price * quantity;
  }
 return total; 
}

function printCartInventory(cart) {
  let inventory = "";
  for (const item in cart){
    inventory += `${Object.values(cart[item])[0]}x${item}\n`;
  }
  return inventory;
  
}

module.exports = {
  calculateCartTotal,
  printCartInventory,
};
```

The part that confuses me is the function calculateCartTotal. What I am confused about is how does this loop know to grab priceInCents? for example, if I was to add another value into the object called "weight: 24" assuming that it is 24 grams, how does the object value skip over quantity and weight and just grab priceInCents? Hopefully I am making sense on how I am confused and that someone has an explanation for me!

Comment: Object.values(cart[item])[1] always grabs the second value in that item dict.

Comment: okay, that makes sense. So if I was to have a third value in that Object.values, how would I make it grab the third value? or even grab the first value?

Comment: that's a really poor way to code by the way - the order of keys in an Object should not be used like that ... `cart[item].qauntity` and `cart[item].priceInCents` should be used

Comment: This is a convoluted way to access Object values. If code changes to add a key between quantity and priceInCents... this would break. Why? the order in Object.values is the same as key : value creation

Comment: Thank you for the advice! New to javascript/coding, so I'll be sure to continue on improving my ways when it comes to writing code and keep this in mind!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you try to run below program then it will be easier for you to visualize everything.

What is happening is item is just the index of element and for an object we can either use the key name to access its value or its index.

You can read [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) doc to understand what `Object.values()` does.

```js
function calculateCartTotal(cart) {
  let total = 0;
  for (const item in cart) {
    console.log(item)
    let quantity = Object.values(cart[item])[0];
    let price = Object.values(cart[item])[1];
        total += price * quantity;
  }
 return total; 
}

var cart = [
    {
        quantity: 2,
        price: 5,
        weight: 24
    },
    {
        quantity: 3,
        price: 10,
        weight: 90
    },
    {
        quantity: 7,
        price: 20,
        weight: 45
    },
    {
        quantity: 1,
        price: 100,
        weight: 67
    }
]

console.log(calculateCartTotal(cart))
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
0
1
2
3
280
```

Program 2 to demonstrate what is happening

```js
function calculateCartTotal(cart) {
 console.log(Object.values(cart[2])[1])
 console.log(cart[2]['price'])
 console.log(cart[2].price)
}

var cart = [
    {
        quantity: 2,
        price: 5,
        weight: 24
    },
    {
        quantity: 3,
        price: 10,
        weight: 90
    },
    {
        quantity: 7,
        price: 20,
        weight: 45
    },
    {
        quantity: 1,
        price: 100,
        weight: 67
    }
]
calculateCartTotal(cart)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
20
20
20
```

Answer (score 0):

I am Deepak,

I can explain (program 2 demonstration). See my friend,you will be able to see the first console.log i.e,  console.log(Object.values(cart[2])[1])...
So, object means the whole cart and .values means the only numbers that a particular object contained. Now, see the result i.e, 20.
So, how this 20 will came?...
Now, see the console.log that I have written before. In the brackets of .value cart of [2](it means that 2 is the position of that cart, that why it is written as cart[2] i.e, inside a cart 2nd position's object and  after cart[2] this one number is there [1], it means inside the 2nd position's object i.e,

OBJECT below:-             position of an objects
var cart = [

```
    quantity: 2,           0 position
    price: 5,
    weight: 24
},
{
    quantity: 3,           1 position
    price: 10,
    weight: 90
},
{
    quantity: 7,           2 position
    price: 20,
    weight: 45
} ,
{
    quantity: 1,           3 position
    price: 100,
    weight: 67
}
```

]

console.log(calculateCartTotal(cart))

Now, match the console.log.
it says that console.log(OBJECT.values(cart[2])[1]);

In the cart, see the 2nd position's object i.e,

{
quantity: 7,           2 position
price: 20,
weight: 45
}

So, cart[2] means the whole object you will above.
[1] means inside the object count the position from 0 onwards. So, in the

```
                          values
```

0 position quantity,            7,
1 position price,               20,
2 position weight.              45.

In the [1] position price: 20.

So, cart[2] means
{
quantity: 7,           2 position
price: 20,
weight: 45
}

And,
[1] means price: 20.

So, your answer is 20.

Note: the numbers that is inside the square brackets will gives the position of an object or inside an object.

Comment: Please edit your formatting.